# C# UWP/WPF MapControl - add a XAML Line Shape between two Geopoints

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml, bing-maps

I want to add a XAML Line shape to connect two Geopoints displayed on a MapControl. However i'm having trouble when anchoring the Line to the Geopoint's. It seems to only work when the second point is +ve in X and +ve in Y from the first (i.e. a line drawn from top left to bottom right). It does not work for other line directions.

The behavior can be experienced in the following example, which will place a green dot at the first point clicked and a blue dot at the second point clicked and then reset. The image shows the result where the black XAML only connects the two points when the blue dot is down/right from the first green dot. The red dashed line is MapPolyline exmaple

Why does drawing lines in the other 3 directions not display correctly?

[image]

**Figure 1** - *Only drawing XAML line top left to bottom right results in correct position of the black xaml line.*

Note im aware that zooming/panning the map after the XAML lines are drawn will always break the connection and it will need to be redrawn,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace MapControlSandbox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        List<BasicGeoposition> ListOfPoints = new List<BasicGeoposition>(); // will hold maximum two points in this example

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void AddCircleToMap(Geopoint nPoint)
        {
            // Add XAML Point
            Ellipse circle = new Ellipse() { Height = 10, Width = 10, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.GreenYellow) };
            mapControl.Children.Add(circle);
            MapControl.SetLocation(circle, nPoint);
            MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(circle, new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.5, 0.5));
        }

        private void mapControl_MapTapped(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapInputEventArgs args)
        {
            var tappedGeoPosition = args.Location.Position;
            var mapPolyline = new MapPolyline();
            
            if (ListOfPoints.Count() > 1)
                ListOfPoints.Clear(); // reset if second point already exists in list

            ListOfPoints.Add(tappedGeoPosition);

            // Add new XAML Point
            Geopoint nPoint = new Geopoint(tappedGeoPosition, AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid);
            AddCircleToMap(nPoint);

            if (ListOfPoints.Count() > 1)
            {
                // Draw a MapPolyline MapElement to connect the two XAML points
                mapPolyline.Path = new Geopath(new List<BasicGeoposition>() { ListOfPoints[0], ListOfPoints[1] }, AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid);               
                mapPolyline.StrokeColor = Windows.UI.Colors.Red;
                mapPolyline.StrokeThickness = 3;
                mapPolyline.StrokeDashed = true;
                mapControl.MapElements.Add(mapPolyline);                              
                                
                // Now Draw a Xaml Line to connect the two XAML points as well
                Windows.Foundation.Point offset1;
                Windows.Foundation.Point offset2;

                var gp1 = new Geopoint(ListOfPoints[0], AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid);
                var gp2 = new Geopoint(ListOfPoints[1], AltitudeReferenceSystem.Ellipsoid);

                mapControl.GetOffsetFromLocation(gp1, out offset1);
                mapControl.GetOffsetFromLocation(gp2, out offset2);

                Line line = new Line()
                {
                    X1 = offset1.X,
                    Y1 = offset1.Y,
                    X2 = offset2.X,
                    Y2 = offset2.Y,                    
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black),
                    StrokeThickness = 1.0,
                };

                mapControl.Children.Add(line);

                //set anchor point to be the point we just added to the map
                MapControl.SetLocation(line, nPoint);

                // tell mapControl where anchor point is relative to the Line shapes dimensions.
                if (offset1.X >= offset2.X && offset1.Y >= offset2.Y)
                { MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(line, new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.0, 0.0)); }
                if (offset1.X <= offset2.X && offset1.Y <= offset2.Y)
                { MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(line, new Windows.Foundation.Point(1.0, 1.0)); }
                if (offset1.X >= offset2.X && offset1.Y <= offset2.Y)
                { MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(line, new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.0, 1.0)); }
                if (offset1.X <= offset2.X && offset1.Y >= offset2.Y)
                { MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(line, new Windows.Foundation.Point(1.0, 0.0)); }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very likely the issue is where you call SetNormalizedAnchorPoint for the Line. Apparently only one of the four cases works. Be aware that you would also use `else if` instead of always checking four conditions.

Comment: i think it is maybe that Line.X1 Y1 Line.X2 Y2 are somehow relative points defining the line rather than the absolute coords as i fixed it for the second line in the image by making line.Y2 = 0 and line.Y1 = offset1.Y - offset2.Y.

Comment: I tried the code and in the other 3 cases, the lines actually are drawn in other places where they should not be. I'm not sure how it happens but I think it should be related to the AnchorPoint and yes, the Line.X1 Y1 Line.X2 Y2 as well. Sometimes, the  Line.X1 Y1 Line.X2 Y2 is so large like 600,600 which obviously can be out of visible view.